# Dropdown value change store access - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to store the changed value from my `select` drop down box inside a string, then access it outside the `change()` function.

How may I accomplish this?

[JSFiddle, Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Sb988/36/)

### HTML

```
<select name="lob-select" class="dk" id="lobSelect">
    <option value="one" id="1">one</option>
    <option value="two" id="2">two</option>
</select>
```

### Jquery

```
var str = ""; 
$( "select[name='lob-select']" ).change(function () {
    str = $("select[name='lob-select'] option:selected").val();
    console.log(str); //this works
}).change();
alert(str); //this doesnt on change
```

Comment: `alert(str)` is only called once on page load, hence why it appear to 'never' change. Only code inside the `change` handler is executed under that event.

Comment: Does this mean i cant access str outside .change()? say in a different function?

Comment: No that will work as long as the `str` value has been set by a `change` event on the select, it's just that your code example is not doing that.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/Sb988/37/

Changed your code slightly:

```
 var str = ""; 
 $( "select[name='lob-select']" ).change(function () {
     str = $("select[name='lob-select'] option:selected").val();
     console.log(str); //this works
 });
// alert(str); //this doesnt on change (THIS HAPPENS ONCE..
```

The alert here will only happen on page load as you have not wrapped it in any events.

```
$(':input[type=button]').click(function(){
   //to show that STR is now changed every time just click this button at any time.
    alert(str);
});
```

if you put it in an event you'll see that whenever you call the event (in this case a button click), you'll see it updates every time it changes.. I also remove the extra .change() part of your code.. There was not much point to it.